# Как реализовать многоуровневое меню с помощю JS?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как сделать многоуровневое выпадающее меню с помощью делегирования событий?

```js
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
var catalog = document.querySelector('.main-ul__catalog');

function openCatalog(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (target.parentNode == catalog) {
    catalogUl.style.display = 'block';
    var arrow = target.parentNode.hasAttributes('arrow');
    if (target == arrow) {
      var elem = target.nextSibling;
      elem.style.display == 'block';
    }
  } else {
    // Все дочерние ul == display : none
  }
}

menu.addEventListener('click', openCatalog, false);
```

```css
.main-ul__catalog-ul {
  display: none;
}

.ul-jewellery {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="main-ul">
    <li class="main-ul__catalog">
      <a href="#">Catalog</a>
      <ul class="main-ul__catalog-ul">
        <li class="arrow">
          <a href="#">Wedding Jewellery</a>
          <ul class="ul-jewellery">
            <li>
              <h4>Wedding Jewellery</h4>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Another item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another item3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">another list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">another list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">another list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">another list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">another list item</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ну разные есть подходы наверно. Я бы ловил click на всём меню, а дальше по this определял конкретный элемент по которому кликнул пользователь.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834699/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-css/834734#834734

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
(function(){
    var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    function openCatalog(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var elem = event.target;

        if(elem.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.className === 'menu'){
            if(!elem.nextElementSibling){
                document.querySelectorAll('.menu ul[style="display: block;"]').forEach(i=>i.style.display = "none");
            } else if(elem.nextElementSibling.style.display !== "block"){
                document.querySelectorAll('.menu ul[style="display: block;"]').forEach(i=>i.style.display = "none");
            }
        } else if(elem.parentElement.parentElement.className === 'main-ul__catalog-ul'){
            if(!elem.nextElementSibling){
                document.querySelectorAll('.main-ul__catalog-ul ul[style="display: block;"]').forEach(i=>i.style.display = "none");
            } else if(elem.nextElementSibling.style.display !== "block"){
                document.querySelectorAll('.main-ul__catalog-ul ul[style="display: block;"]').forEach(i=>i.style.display = "none");
            }
        }
        if(elem.nextElementSibling){
            elem.nextElementSibling.style.display === 'block' 
                ? elem.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none'
                : elem.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
    menu.addEventListener('click', openCatalog, false);
})();
```