# Раскрывающийся список на css

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

[image: Список]

Можно ли создать такой список с помощью bootstrap? Если да, то подскажите пример. Если нет, то подскажите как без bootstrap. Чем проще, тем лучше.

Comment: bootstrap - это всего то немного html классов, css и js красоты.

Comment: а скролл обязателен?

Comment: @Избытоксусликов Да)

Comment: @RafaelShepard, можно и без Bootstrap. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/824239/280567

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Смена узла при раскрытии дерева](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/824239/%d0%a1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень давно делал такую штуку для одного туристического сайта.

И вот их код опять пригодилось.

Тут есть лишный `HTML` код я думаю сами справитесь если вы владеете `HTML`-ом на средном уровне

Скролл появляется при клике одного плюса то есть если в него есть нужды

Реализовано на **jQuery** как бы я его не любил и плюс это старый код

Не сто процентно так как у вас в картинке но если потратить часок 2 то можете сделать полную копию

Удачи

```js
$(".summary").click(function(){
    var acSel = '#' + $(this).attr('aria-controls');

    if ($(acSel).is(":hidden")) {
        $(acSel).slideDown("slow");
    }
    else {
     $(acSel).hide("slow");   
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
body {
  width:50%;
}
.tab_content {
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height:600px;
}
.is-hidden {
 display: none;
}
.summary {
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 14px 40px;
 position: relative;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: 400;
}
.summary:before {
 /*-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0);*/
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    will-change: translate,rotate;
}
.summary:after {
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    will-change: translate,opacity;

}
.summary.open:before{ /* добавочный класс */
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-0deg);
    width:0;
}
.summary:after,
.summary:before {
 content: "";
 width: 14px;
 height: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 background-color: #37454d;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 opacity: 1;
 left: 21px;
 contain: strict;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
  <section class="details">
  <h4 class="summary" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="hotel-facilities" aria-controls="hotel-facilities" tabindex="0">Hotel facilities</h4>
  <div id="hotel-facilities" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">24-hour reception (4923)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">24-hour room service (286)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Airport shuttle (602)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
      <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Beach umbrellas (2094)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Bungalows (152)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Business center (3052)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
        <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Casino (113)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
   
  </div>
</section>
<section class="details">
  <h4 class="summary" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="lodging-type" aria-controls="lodging_type" tabindex="0">Type of lodging</h4>
  <div id="lodging_type" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox"  name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Bed & Breakfast (427)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox"  name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Camping Site (27)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox"  name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Hostel (121)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox"  name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Hotel (8967)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
   
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox"  name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Serviced Apartment (493)</span>
      </label>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
<section class="details">
  <h4 class="summary" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="food_and_beverages" aria-controls="food_and_beverages" tabindex="0">Food and beverages</h4>
  <div id="food_and_beverages" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Offers all inclusive deals (35)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Serves Halal (6)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Serves Kosher Food (6)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="details">
  <h4 class="summary" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="childcare" aria-controls="childcare" tabindex="0">For Children</h4>
  <div id="childcare" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Child / Baby cot (2651)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Childcare / Babysitting (386</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Kids' club (61)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
     <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Kids' playground (317)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
     <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Organized activities for kids (55)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="details">
  <h4 class="summary" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="wellness" aria-controls="wellness" tabindex="0">Wellness / Spa</h4>
  <div id="wellness" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Beauty Salon (323)</span>
      </label>
    </div>

 
     
      <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Steam room (266)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="details">
  <h4 class="summary" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="aHotelSize" aria-controls="aHotelSize" tabindex="0">Number of rooms</h4>
  <div id="aHotelSize" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">1-50 (1318)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">51-150 (1207)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">150+ (595)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="details">
  <h4 class="summary" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="hotel_chain" aria-controls="hotel_chain" tabindex="0">Hotel chain</h4>
  <div id="hotel_chain" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">7 Days Inn (3)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">APA Hotels (2)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Belmond (1)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Best Western (1)</span>
      </label>
    </div> <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">


  
   
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Design Hotels (2)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Doubletree (41)</span>
      </label>
    </div> <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Dusit (1)</span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">FairBridge Inn & Suites (2)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="details">
  <h4 class="summary" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="room_facilities" aria-controls="room_facilities" tabindex="0">Room facilities</h4>
  <div id="room_facilities" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Air conditioning (8299)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Balcony / Terrace (2995)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Cable TV (6378)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Central heating (5449)</span>
      </label>



    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Free WiFi in the rooms (3064)</span>
      </label>
    </div> <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Hairdryer (8319)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Hypoallergenic bedding (127)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Ironing board (8058)</span>
      </label>
    </div> <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Kitchen / Kitchenette (8177)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Microwave (9994)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Refrigerator (10370)</span>
      </label>
    </div> <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Room safe (1085)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Satellite TV (7527)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Telephone (6629)</span>
      </label>
    </div> <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Television (12046)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">WiFi in the rooms (6030)</span>
      </label>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
<section class="details">
  <h4 class="summary" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="sport_facilities" aria-controls="sport_facilities" tabindex="0">Sport facilities</h4>
  <div id="sport_facilities" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Archery / Shooting (109)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Badminton (72)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Bike Rental (1251)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
     <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Bathroom with shower (6985)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Billiards (1012)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Boats to Rent (1119)</span>
      </label>
    </div> <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Bowling (912)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Diving (523)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Fitness / Aerobics (1511)</span>
      </label>
    </div> <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Golf Course (3432)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Hiking trail (2194)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Horse riding (1028)</span>
      </label>
    </div> <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Indoor tennis court (8319)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Minigolf (575)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Sailing (947)</span>
      </label>
    </div> <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Skiing (470)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Squash (208)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Surfing (834)</span>
      </label>
    </div> <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Table Tennis (1085)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Tennis Court (7527)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Volleyball / Beach Volleyball (613)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="details">
  <h4 class="summary" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="hotel_theme" aria-controls="hotel_theme" tabindex="0">Theme / Type</h4>
  <div id="hotel_theme" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Airport Hotel (275)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Beachfront Hotel (542)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Boutique Hotel (509)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
     <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Centrally Located Hotel (3463)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Club Hotel (91)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Convention Center Hotel (588)</span>
      </label>
    </div> <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Country Hotel (728)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Design Hotel (212)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
   

  </div>
</section>
<section class="details">
  <h4 class="summary" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="suitable_for" aria-controls="suitable_for" tabindex="0">Suitable fore</h4>
  <div id="suitable_for" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Adults only (108)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
   

    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Singles (655)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Winter Sports Enthuisasts (301)</span>
      </label>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
<section class="details">
  <h4 class="summary" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="accessibility" aria-controls="accessibility" tabindex="0">Accessibility</h4>
  <div id="accessibility" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Accessible parking (2108)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Accessible paths / corridors (1852)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Deaf accessibility equipment (1046)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
     <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Wheelchair accessible (4350)</span>
      </label>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошо! Спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

По-моему оптимальное и простое решение ^_^ :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 $.fn.extend({
     toggleText: function(a, b){
         return this.text(this.text() == b ? a : b);
     }
 });
    
 $('.list_item > a').click(function(event) {
  
  $(this).children('span').toggleText('+', '-');
  $(this).next('.second_list').slideToggle(200);
 });
 $('.second_list_item > a').click(function(event) {
  $(this).children('span').toggleText('+', '-');
  $(this).next('.third_list').slideToggle(200);
 });



});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.list .list_item {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.list .list_item a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
.list .list_item span {
  margin-right: 4px;
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
.list .list_item .open .arrow_icon {
  margin-top: -20px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.list .list_item .arrow_icon {
  margin-left: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: auto;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.list .list_item_toggler {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.list .list_item_toggler a {
  line-height: 32px;
}

.second_list, .third_list{
  display: none;
}
.second_list{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.third_list{
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="list">
  <div class="list_item">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <span>+</span>
      блюдо №1
    </a>
    <div class="second_list">
      <div class="second_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span>+</span>
          Блюдо №1

        </a>
        <div class="third_list">
          <a href="#">Салат №1</a>
          <a href="#">Салат №2</a>
          <a href="#">Салат №3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="second_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span>+</span>
          Блюдо №1

        </a>
        <div class="third_list">
          <a href="#">Салат №1</a>
          <a href="#">Салат №2</a>
          <a href="#">Салат №3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="second_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span>+</span>
          Блюдо №1

        </a>
        <div class="third_list">
          <a href="#">Салат №1</a>
          <a href="#">Салат №2</a>
          <a href="#">Салат №3</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list_item">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <span>+</span>
      блюдо №1
    </a>
    <div class="second_list">
      <div class="second_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span>+</span>
          Блюдо №1

        </a>
        <div class="third_list">
          <a href="#">Салат №1</a>
          <a href="#">Салат №2</a>
          <a href="#">Салат №3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="second_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span>+</span>
          Блюдо №1

        </a>
        <div class="third_list">
          <a href="#">Салат №1</a>
          <a href="#">Салат №2</a>
          <a href="#">Салат №3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="second_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span>+</span>
          Блюдо №1

        </a>
        <div class="third_list">
          <a href="#">Салат №1</a>
          <a href="#">Салат №2</a>
          <a href="#">Салат №3</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Стилизацию настроете под себя)

Без лишних bootstrap-овских штучек)

Comment: Отличный вариант! Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно на Bootstrap, то есть готовые части кода, называются сниппеты.
Вот две ссылки на два похожих, как в примере сниппета списка на Bootstrap(там анимации ещё,и стилизация, но её можно спокойно убрать,внизу код можно выполнить прямо на странице), если поискать, то можно найти больше, и помимо Bootstrap есть еще хорошие фреймворки Materialize, Foundation, Semantic ui и тд. В них тоже часто можно найти хорошие сниппеты.

1. [Первая ссылка](http://bootstraptema.ru/stuff/snippets_bootstrap/menu/vertical_accordion_menu_md/24-1-0-1816)
2. [Вторая ссылка](http://bootstraptema.ru/stuff/snippets_bootstrap/menu/adaptivnoe_blok_menju_4_urovnja_slinky/24-1-0-792)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

А можно вообще без скриптов.

Стиля:

```
li {list-style-type:none;}
ul {padding-left:20px;}
input[type="checkbox"] {margin-left:-20px;}
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + ul li {display:none;}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox"/> Кухня и столовая
        <ul>
            <li>Кухни</li></li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"/> Столы
                <ul>
                    <li>Круглые</li>
                    <li>Синие</li>
                    <li>Гладкие</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Буфеты</li>
            <li>Стулья</li>
            <li>Стойки</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Спальня</li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox"/> Детская
        <ul>
            <li>Шкафы</li>
            <li>Воплегасители</li>
            <li>Топотопоглотители</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Прихожая</li>
</ul>
```

Чекбоксы, разумеется, обстилить чтобы были похожи на плюсики-минусики.